# separate countdown for divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-countdown

I want to show countdown in each of my divs. Right now I get the seconds from my database and store in in data-countdown attribute and then use the following js code for countdown. Only the first div changes the value every second and the other ones do not change.
Here is the fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/j61qs7oc/

```
//imagine this line of code in every loop of a for loop so $remaining will be different
<div style="font-size: 25px; color:#e3b40b ; font-weight: 600;" data-countdown="'.$remaining.'"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></div>
```

here is the js code

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {

finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
var $this = $(this);
timeout = null;
time = null;
startCountdown($this,finalDate, 1000, end);

function startCountdown(display,timen, pause, callback) {
    time = timen;
    display.html(timen);

    if (timen == 0)
        callback();
    else {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            startCountdown(display,timen - 1, pause, callback)
        }, pause);
    }
}

function end() {
    alert();
}
});
```

Comment: what you want to done ?.. could you explain more

Comment: @SunnyS.M look at my Fiddle. I want each div have a separate countdown

Comment: hmmm I'm late.. it has solved

Comment: here(  http://fiddle.jshell.net/j61qs7oc/2/  )  I update the code but already solved by Brandon Gano....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a variable without using the `var` keyword, you're creating a global. So each instance of your countdown is overwriting the previous value of `finalDate`, `timeout`, and `time`. Try adding `var` before each of those lines and it should do what you need. i.e.:

```
var finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
var $this = $(this);
var timeout = null;
var time = null;
startCountdown($this,finalDate, 1000, end);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do this in regular Javascript instead of jQuery...

```js
var countdownDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-countdown]');

function end() {
    alert();
}
function countdown(display, timen, pause, callback) {
    display.innerHTML = timen;

    if (timen == 0) callback();
    else {
        display.timeout;
        clearTimeout(display.timeout);
        display.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            countdown(display, timen - 1, pause, callback)
        }, pause);
    }
}

for(var i = countdownDivs.length>>>0; i--;){
    countdown(countdownDivs[i], countdownDivs[i].dataset.countdown, 1000, end);
}
```

```css
div[data-countdown]{
    font-size:25px;
    color:#e3b40b;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<div data-countdown="12312312"></div>

<div data-countdown="555555"></div>

<div data-countdown="95695"></div>
```